# Distributed source control for VisualWorks Smalltalk

Tags: dvcs, smalltalk, visualworks

One of the annoying things about Smalltalk is that it (usually) requires its own VCS, due to the way that it manages its source code.  Squeak and Gemstone (at least in its GLASS version) have a DVCS called Monticello that works passably well.  As near as I can tell, VisualWorks' main VCS, StORE, only works in old-fashioned centralized mode.  Is there a system similar to Monticello available for VisualWorks?  Alternatively, am I misunderstanding the right way to use StORE?

Comment: +1 for just asking a smalltalk question :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While Store is not structured to be a distributed tool, it can be used that way.  Most of the engineers working on VisualWorks and ObjectStudio use a local repository (in their office; most of the team is geographically distributed).  There are merging and replication tools that allows them to synch up their local work with the "repository of record" as required/desired.

Having said that, there's a port of Monticello for VW (and thus, for ObjectStudio as well).  The only real issue with it is that after publishing, it doesn't "talk" to the tools (browser) about the publish status.  That's because it's mostly use to maintain the Seaside port, and not as a mainline versioning tool for VW.